# Backbone.js collection get does not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

```
var sgt1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: sgt2
    });

var a = new sgt1();
a.add({attr1: 'asd'});
```

Ok, up to now it is works but:

`a.get(0)` returns undefined

and

`a.at(0)` returns an obj

Why does `get` return `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.get(0)` fetches by ID. It is not the same as `at` which fetches by index position. Since your model does not yet have an ID, `get` would not work.

Answer (score 2):

With `get()` you query the collection by the models `id` field and not by its index like with `at()`. Please refer to the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get).